# How to share a Windows 7 Library while preserving its 'one-ness'?

Tags: windows-7, windows, smb

My media server with all my movies is running Windows 7. I have two folders on different drives I want to share, E:\Movies and F:\Movies, so I've combined them with a library called "Movies," so I can copy and access movies from one folder/share. Unfortunately when I share it, Windows just creates two shares, Movies and Movies2 for each folder in the library.

Any way to share the library as one share?

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/210408/how-to-expose-2-folders-as-1-network-share-in-windows-7