# How can I make one folder/share link to multiple different folders?

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2008-r2, nfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to expose 2 folders as 1 network share in windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/210408/how-to-expose-2-folders-as-1-network-share-in-windows-7)

So I've tried NTFS Junction Points and DFS and I can't either of them to do what I want.

I have C:\Movies, E:\Movies, and F:\Movies. I want to make them appear as 1 share or folder, such as \something\Movies or C:\Movies and it show everything from ALL of the folders.

DFS seems to only work with folders that have THE SAME contents in each folder, not aggregate all the info into one share :-/

NFTS Junction points won't let me make one "link" to multiple locations either.

Any ideas?

Comment: the problem I see is what if two different locations have different files with the same name.  I'm not sure if NFS can do this either.

Comment: Minus the fact there was no real answer 1 year ago and plenty of things could have changed..

Comment: Why not add that request for current (possible) updates as a comment to the original question and throw a bounty on it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, check this out.  About as close as I can get

Setup a Linux box that mounts each of the shares.  Something like this in /etc/fstab:

```
//WindowsServer/MoviesC /mnt/moviesC cifs username=johndoe,password=johndoepassword 0 0

//WindowsServer/MoviesE /mnt/moviesE cifs username=johndoe,password=johndoepassword 0 0

//WindowsServer/MoviesF /mnt/moviesF cifs username=johndoe,password=johndoepassword 0 0
```

Or you could move all the drives to the Linux box and have them all mount under something similar (i.e. `/movies/disk1`, `/movies/disk2`, etc..)

Then using Samba on the Linux server you share out `/mnt` as Movies.  Then you would access `\\LinuxServer\Movies` from anywhere and have all the drives there...albeit in subfolders but at least it would look like one drive.

Anybody looked at FreeNAS...it might have some capability like this too.